# Can we use @autowired on an entity object in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a entity class called `Customer`, I am using this entity object in another class to set the data. When I use this object below like

```
@Autowired
Customer customer
```

Spring is complaining  that please configure the bean in your classes.

Can we use auto wiring with entity objects?

Comment: Why would you want to autowire an entity? That's exactly the thing you *wouldn't* autowire.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only *autowire* only those beans whose life-cycle are managed by [*Spring IoC container*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans).

These beans are defined in `xml` form with `</bean>` tag, or with some special annotations like `@Bean`, `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` etc.

**On the other hand,**

in simple terms, entities are some java objects that you will need to create, update by yourself according to your business logic and save/update/remove them in/from DB. Their life-cycle cannot be managed by *Spring IoC container*.

So, you should never feel like you need to *autowire* an `entity` if you are doing it right!

Comment: so I have to go with using new keyword in order to create entity object??

Comment: @Rocky4Ever Yes that is right. And for existing entities in DB, you can just fetch them using `JPA/Hibernate`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Spring support `@Autowire` only for Spring Beans. A java class becomes Spring Bean only when it is created by Spring, otherwise it is not.

A workaround might be to annotate your class with `@Configurable` but you would have to use AspectJ

Please look in the Spring documentations on how to use `@Configurable`

Also, I wonder why you would autowire an entity class ?

Answer (score 1):

I would warn you not to mix Spring Bean and JPA entities in one class/usecase because:

- Spring Beans are instantiated and managed by Spring
- Entities are managed by JPA provider

Answer (score 0):

If you mean JPAs @Entity-annotation, Spring is simply telling you, that there isn't a bean in its context.
On startup/runtime classes in the application will be scanned and each class annotated with spring annotations like @Component, @Service etc. will be instantiated as beans and put into a global context (Spring applicationcontext).
This context is then used to lookup and inject those beans into other beans when @Autowired is found during scanning.

Opposed to this, @Entity is used during the creation of the Persistence-Context of JPA (as far as I remember) which isn't aware of Spring and it's context.

Most of the solutions to make both contexts aware of each other a mostly a little bit hacky.