# Spring boot using Autowire Cofiguration property class in Entity class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have to use some set data member class in Spring entity class

Current Entity class

```
Entity(name="users")
public class Users{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name=ID")
private long Id;

@Column(name=NAME")
private String name;


@Column(name=AGE")
private String age;

@Column(name=PIN")
private String pin;

public Users(String name, String age, String pin)
{
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.pin = pin;

}

}
```

Now I need to add a new Member which is unique to that place
areaId, we run sperate application per each area so this will be passed from command line arguments or config properties during application starts.

My properties class looks like below

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("user.info")
public class UserProperties{

public String areaId;

public String getAreaID(){return this.areaId;}
public void setAreaID(String areaId){ this.areaId = areaId;}

}

users:
  info:
    areaId:124
```

I have to store this and initializes also during Users object constructing, here I am trying to make simple

```
Entity(name="users")
public class Users{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name=ID")
private long Id;

@Column(name=NAME")
private String name;


@Column(name=AGE")
private String age;

@Column(name=PIN")
private String pin;

@Column(name=AREAID")
private String areaId;

public Users(String name, String age, String pin)
{
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.pin = pin;
this.areaId = ""//?? how to get area id  directly ? 
}

}
```

I can not change the constructor of Users because it demands changes in the other application which are using  this lib

Want to Autowire a users properties class inside Entity class(but this is not suggestable as read in some [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014047/can-we-use-autowired-on-an-entity-object-in-spring) )

What would be the best way to initialize that default kind of variable?

Comment: >>>"I can not change the constructor of Users because it demands changes in the other application which are using this lib."


But you can add another constructor

Comment: Still new constructo should be called to take this effect , else no use of adding the extra param

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your property is something static.

Then get it from a static way at start.

There's several ways to get command line value at start directly or in a static block:

```
static {

(your code here)

}
```

You'll can put @Column on a getter on this property after that.