# Autowired Repository is null with JPA Auditing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, audit

I am trying to insert audit record in audit_trial table through `postpersist` or my `transactional` entities. However, the `auditrial` repository is null even though I have provided `autowired`. Below is my code. please suggest what I am missing in the code.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AuditEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private AuditTrialRepository auditTrialRepository;

@PostPersist
    public void saveInsertAudit(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {

        AuditTrial auditTrial = new AuditTrial();
        auditTrial.setAction(INSERT);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        if (null != object) {
            auditTrial.setModule(getModule(object));
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            if (null != json) {
                auditTrial.setAfterImage(json);
                auditTrialRepository.save(auditTrial);
            }
        }

}



@Repository
public interface AuditTrialRepository extends JpaRepository<AuditTrial, Long> {

}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014047/can-we-use-autowired-on-an-entity-object-in-spring

Comment: Is anything in the logs about failing to autowire it? How are you enabling Spring Data JPA? do you have a starter in your dependencies or using `@EnableJpaRepositories`?

Comment: All other repositories are working. I suspect its because of the postpersist event in which, it takes the context of entity.

Comment: You can test that theory by removing the method or at least the `@PostPersist` annotation.

Comment: yep, it works without postpersist